# How do I list all background processes?

Tags: ps, background-process, jobs

Is it possible to list all running background processes with the `ps` command, or is the only option for getting a list of background processes the `jobs` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"background processes" usually refers to terminal job control. That would be processes that are in process groups that are not the foreground process group of their controlling terminal device.

On Linux systems with the `procps` implementation of `ps`, you can find them with:

```
ps -eo pid,pgid,tpgid,args | awk 'NR == 1 || ($3 != -1 && $2 != $3)'
```

Where we look for processes where `tpgid` (the terminal foreground process group id) is not `-1` (the processes that have a controlling terminal) and where their process group id is not the tpgid.

Note that it will also include the shells that are currently busy waiting for a foreground job (including the one where you run that pipeline from if run in foreground in a terminal) as they will have put those jobs in foreground and will be therefore by definition themselves in background.

Answer (score 9):

The `jobs` command will show any background jobs started within the current shell, usually by starting a background task with the `&` operator or `^Z bg` (e.g. `sleep 10 &`).

If you want to see all of the background processes running on the system, you can use `ps -e`, or `ps -eF` to get some additional details.

To get more information about what commands are able to do, you can run almost always run `man ps`  (replacing `ps` with any command) to get the manual page with lots of info.